TypeScript Type Errors in Formik Components - How to Resolve?
I'm working on a TypeScript project where I'm using Formik for my forms. However, I'm encountering type errors in my components that I can't seem to fix.
This is my input.tsx file that I created with ShadCN and modified a little.
const inputVariants = cva(...);

export type TInputProps = React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> & VariantProps<typeof inputVariants> & {
  label: string;
  id: string;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  disabled?: boolean;
};

export type TInputFormikProps = TInputProps & FieldHookConfig<string>;

const Input = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, TInputProps>(
  ({ className, disabled, variant, children, label, type, ...props }, ref) => {

...

    return (
      <div className="styling">
        <label
          htmlFor={props.id}
          className={cn('styling')}>
          {label}
        </label>
        <div className="styling">
          <input
            type={type}
            className={cn(inputVariants({ variant, className }), disabledInput)}
            ref={ref}
            disabled={disabled}
            {...props}
          />
          {children && <div>{modifiedChildren}</div>}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
);

Input.displayName = 'Input';

export { Input, inputVariants };

This is the TextInputField.tsx file, which uses Formik. The idea was to create two types: TInputProps and TInputFormikProps, as you can see in the input.tsx file. One type is for the input that is used without Formik (TInputProps), while TInputFormikProps is used in the TextInputField.tsx file and includes all the necessary properties Formik would need.
import { FieldAttributes, useField } from 'formik';
import React from 'react';
import { Input, TInputFormikProps } from 'input';

const TextInputField:  React.FC<FieldAttributes<TInputFormikProps>> = ({
  name,
  children = null,
    label,
    id,
  ...props
}) => {
  const [field, meta] = useField(name);
  const { touched, error } = meta;

  return (
    <>
      <Input [error here]
        {...props}
        {...field}
        label={label}
        id={id}
        className={touched && error ? 'styling' : ''}
      >
        {children}
      </Input>
      {touched && error ? (
        <div className="styling">{error}</div>
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
};

export { TextInputField };

the error I get from the <Input...
TS2322: Type
{ children: string | number | boolean | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | Iterable<ReactNode> | null; ... 301 more ...; variant?: "standard" | ... 3 more ... | undefined; } | ... 7 more ... | { ...; }
is not assignable to type
IntrinsicAttributes & InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> & VariantProps<(props?: (ConfigVariants<{     
variant: {         
standard: string;         
iconRight: string;         
iconInside: string;     
}; }> & ClassProp) | undefined) => string> & { ...; } & RefAttributes<...>

Type
{ children: string | number | boolean | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | Iterable<ReactNode> | null; ... 301 more ...; variant?: "standard" | ... 3 more ... | undefined; }
is not assignable to type  RefAttributes<HTMLInputElement> 
Types of property  ref  are incompatible.
Type  LegacyRef<HTMLSelectElement> | undefined  is not assignable to type  LegacyRef<HTMLInputElement> | undefined 
Type  (instance: HTMLSelectElement | null) => void  is not assignable to type  LegacyRef<HTMLInputElement> | undefined 
Type  (instance: HTMLSelectElement | null) => void  is not assignable to type  (instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void 
Types of parameters  instance  and  instance  are incompatible.
Type  HTMLInputElement | null  is not assignable to type  HTMLSelectElement | null 
Type  HTMLInputElement  is missing the following properties from type  HTMLSelectElement :
length, options, selectedIndex, selectedOptions

error
